# Quadric functions on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be  a Riemannian manifold such that the parallel transport along every simple closed curve is the identity operator. A smooth function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ is called  a quadric function if for every two points $x,y \in M$ we have $H(f)(x)=P_{xy}^{*}H(f)(y)$ where
$P_{xy}$ is the parallel transport from $x$ to $y$.(With respect to an arbitrary curve which joins $x$ to $y$).

> Is the product of two affine functions, a quadric function?
>
> Can we write every quadric function as a linear combination of terms in the form $fg$ where $f$ and $g$ are affine functions?

Comment: Your assumption means that the metric g is locally flat. Now you can solve your own problem. In any case, this is more suitable for the MSE, since it is not at research level.

Comment: @Misha  How can we globalize?

Comment: Suppose you are dealing with complete manifolds. The  you are looking at quadratic/linear functions on $R^n$ which are invariant under the action of the Bieberbach group of covering transformations. Such functions hardly ever exist (you can classify when).